# Why doesn't this abstract class output anything in Php?

Tags: php, oop

Why does this abstract class not work and output nothing?

```
<?php
abstract class Con {
    function __construct($name);
    }
}
class Shop extends Con {
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->shopname = $name;
    }
    function write() {
        echo $this->shopname;
    }
    function outputdate() {
        echo ' ' . date('Y');
    }
    function __destruct() {
        $this->outputdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: compiler error: `PHP Fatal error:  Non-abstract method Con::__construct() must contain body`. enable errors: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: are you missing an open bracket `{` on line 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define some class in other class body. Instead, you must use PHP OOP features to extend one class from another.

```
class Shop extends Con{
...code goes here....
}
$shop = new Shop('shopname');
$shop->write();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate an abstract class. Also, you can't create a class within another class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type

Check out this link if you are looking to subclass.

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: I don't see any classes in classes, I only see poorly indented code.

Comment: sorry I think the formatiing is wrong... I found out from comment it does not contain a body to the method in the abstract class..

Comment: Class `shop` is within his class `con`